# why is the domain of $\sec^{-1} x$, $\mathbb{R}- (-1 ,1)$? why can't $x$ take a values like 0.2, 0.3, etc?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the domain of $\sec^{-1} x$, $\mathbb{R}- (-1 ,1)$?  why can't $x$ take a values like $0.2, 0.3$ or $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sec^{-1}x=\theta \rightarrow x=\sec\theta$. Now what is the range of $\sec\theta$? Can it take values like $0,0.2,0.3$?